# How to issue query in multi-layer has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think it is a classical problem but I don't how to name it.

Suppose I have three models A, B, C.
A has many B, B has many C. Now I have a A, how can I query all the Cs which belong to that A through some B in Rails?

Currently my best solution is to query all Bs that belongs to that A and then extract a array contains all Bs's id and issue another query to get all Cs' B_id in this array.

But I wonder whether there is an elegant(or built-in) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this kind of shortcut using **`has_many :through`**.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

> The has_many :through association is also useful for setting up
>   "shortcuts" through nested has_many associations. For example, if a
>   document has many sections, and a section has many paragraphs, you may
>   sometimes want to get a simple collection of all paragraphs in the
>   document. You could set that up this way:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
  has_many :paragraphs, through: :sections
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
  has_many :paragraphs
end

class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
end
```